# What does {"d":""} means in asp.net webservice response

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services

I've created a simple C# asp.net web service function which returns a string message
and I am calling it from page using jquery ajax.

C#:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //alert("ready");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; chatset=utf-8",
            url: "WebService2.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                //alert(msg); //doesnt works
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    });
```

My question is that why does  `alert(msg);` doesnt works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a security hardening mechanism.

Essentially, it helps protecting against CSRF type of attacks where the attacker reads a JavaScript array (downloaded as Json) from a victim website. They can do that by overriding JavaScript's Array type. `d` causes the returned Json to not be an array and thus turns Array overriding useless for the attacker.

See this great blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx

Comment: +1 thanks, This means that only for "Array overriding" issue MS developers have added the {d:""} variable

Comment: not at all nithin. read his answer carefully. "cross site request forgery attack" there is also a way to simulate XSS attack using this vulnerability.

Answer (score 8):

> ASP.NET and WCF JSON service endpoints actually wrap their JSON in an
>   object with the “d” property to circumvent a  subtle potential
>   security flaw when using JSON

Phil Haack's post on this: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx

This was introduced from ASP.NET3.5. If you want `msg` to work in both frameworks before and after 3.5, just try this small hack.

```
var data = msg.hasOwnProperty("d") ? msg.d : msg;
```

Courtesy Dave Ward: [Never worry about ASP.NET AJAX’s .d again](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/)

Comment: Yeah, basically my answer above.