# Why we use data.d while get response from ajax json call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am using `AJAX` call from my Html page to call a method from my asmx.cs file, using below code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxCall() {               
            var UserName = $("#<%=lblUsername.ClientID %>").text();                
            $("#passwordAvailable").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'webServiceDemo.asmx/CheckOldPassword',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ UserName: UserName }),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (JSON.parse(data.d) != "success") // Why we need to use "data.d" ??                                  
                    {
                        $("#passwordAvailable").attr("src", "App_Themes/NewTheme/images/deleteICN.gif");
                        $("#<%=txtOldPwd.ClientID %>").css({ 'border': '1px solid red' });
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#passwordAvailable").attr("src", "App_Themes/NewTheme/images/signoff.gif");
                    }
                }                    
            });
        }
    </script>
```

So my **Question** is why do we need to use `data.d` ? Why does all data is being stored in `.d` and what is `.d`?

Because when I use only `data` it's not giving me correct return values but when I used `data.d` it does.

please give me suggestions.

**Server side code C#**

```
[WebMethod]
    public string CheckOldPassword(string UserName)
    {
// code here
string sRtnValue = "success";
return sRtnValue;
}
```

so `d` is not property or variable but still  I got value in `.d`
Thanks

Comment: Can't answer without the JSON code.

Comment: `data` is the JSON object returned from the endpoint. `d` is one of the properties of it, you are checking if the `d` property of `data` is equal to the string 'success'.

Comment: You can answer without the JSON code... The server is returning JSON with a variable named `d`

Comment: `.d` is not any property or variable please see the updated post

Comment: c# 3.5 and above puts all data into the variable 'd'.

Comment: Why downvote ? - leave the comment if `downvote`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does {"d":""} means in asp.net webservice response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227427/what-does-d-means-in-asp-net-webservice-response)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C# 3.5 and above will serialize all JSON responses into a variable `d`.

When the server sends a JSON response it will have a signature similar to this:

```
{
    "d" : {
        "variable" : "value"
    }
}
```

With a `console.log(data)` inside the ajax success function you'll see the  responses data structure in the browser console.