# ASPX Codebehind call Page Client script from WebMethod

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASPX page that calls the server with an AJAX call that is inside a javascript function. I need to process the (json) data that is sent to the server via and then return data from the server back to the client and call a function with parameters.

**My ajax code**

```
function () {
        var myVar= "ooooblah";
       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyPage.aspx/TestFunc",
            data: "{val:'" + myVar + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess
    });
}
```

**My code behind aspx.cs**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void TestFunc(string val)
{
    //process code here
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(...); //tried using this but it don't work
}
```

The error I get when I try to compile is :

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Control.Page'
>
> Error  CS0026  Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

Do I need to put it outside in the Page_Load?
Not sure how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to call a javascript function from C# because that's a "stateless" (lets say) POST call, and that call runs outside the page context. That method could be in any other class and the result would be the same, **you won't have access neither to the Controls array nor the Page properties, that's why the method is static**.

What you can do is to add a more complex response as a hint to the OnSuccess function. So the OnSuccess function could check: "Hey if I get an ExtraArgsForMagicFunction property in the response it means that I need to call my magic function"

On the Client

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myVar= "ooooblah";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebMethodTest.aspx/TestFunc",
        data: "{val:'" + myVar + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: onSuccess
    });

    function onSuccess(data) {
        alert(data.d.MainResponse);

        if (data.d.ExtraArgsForMagicFunction) {
            magicFunction(data.d.ExtraArgsForMagicFunction)
        }
    }

    function magicFunction(args) {
        alert(args[0]);
    }
</script>
```

On the server

```
[Serializable]
public struct FuncResult
{
    public string MainResponse;
    public string[] ExtraArgsForMagicFunction;
}
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static FuncResult TestFunc(string val)
{
    return new FuncResult()
    {
        MainResponse = val + "Response",
        ExtraArgsForMagicFunction = new[] { "Some Extra Args" }
    };
}
```

If you get a 401 check this out [ASP.NET Calling WebMethod with jQuery AJAX "401 (Unauthorized)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized)

If you want to know "Why `d`?" check this out [What does {"d":""} means in asp.net webservice response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227427/what-does-d-means-in-asp-net-webservice-response)

Comment: Thanks but I don't think you understood my question... I am able to go from JavaScript to C# (codebehind) ... what I'm having problem doing is calling a separate javascript function when I'm in C#... I can hit the success just fine

Comment: Thanks but I was able to get the ajax working...Turns out I wasn't formatting JSON data correctly