# Is it possible to change a page webmethod response in JSON, removing the .d node?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, vb.net, web-services

I know I can achieve this with a ASHX handler, but i really need it from a page webmethod.

I'm calling a page webmethod from in page javascript using this code:

```
        $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/teste-datatables.aspx/getdata") %>',data: '{ a: ' + id + '}', contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                        console.log( response);
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('textStatus:' + textStatus);
                        console.log('errorThrown:' + errorThrown);
                        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                    }
            });
```

I have a JSON file teste.json (just to keep put database interactions and facilitate tests from you guys):

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    [
      "Airi",
      "Satou",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "28th Nov 08",
      "$162,700"
    ],
    [
      "Angelica",
      "Ramos",
      "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "London",
      "9th Oct 09",
      "$1,200,000"
    ],
    [
      "Ashton",
      "Cox",
      "Junior Technical Author",
      "San Francisco",
      "12th Jan 09",
      "$86,000"
    ],
    [
      "Bradley",
      "Greer",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "13th Oct 12",
      "$132,000"
    ],
    [
      "Brenden",
      "Wagner",
      "Software Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "7th Jun 11",
      "$206,850"
    ],
    [
      "Brielle",
      "Williamson",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "New York",
      "2nd Dec 12",
      "$372,000"
    ],
    [
      "Bruno",
      "Nash",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "3rd May 11",
      "$163,500"
    ],
    [
      "Caesar",
      "Vance",
      "Pre-Sales Support",
      "New York",
      "12th Dec 11",
      "$106,450"
    ],
    [
      "Cara",
      "Stevens",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "New York",
      "6th Dec 11",
      "$145,600"
    ],
    [
      "Cedric",
      "Kelly",
      "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "29th Mar 12",
      "$433,060"
    ]
  ]
}
```

And tried several variations in webmethod...

**Test1** Load JSON from file to string and then return it

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json), System.Web.Services.WebMethod(True)>
Public Shared Function getdata(a As Integer) As String
    Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/teste.json")
    Dim jsonString As String = File.ReadAllText(path)
    Return jsonString.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
End Function
```

The result is:

```
{d: "{  "draw": 1,  "recordsTotal": 57,  "recordsFilter ... gh",      "29th Mar 12",      "$433,060"    ]  ]}"}
```

**Test2** Load JSON from file to string, convert it to datablesnet object and then serealize it and write to current context

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json), System.Web.Services.WebMethod(True)>
Public Shared Sub getdata6(a As Integer)
    Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/teste.json")
    Dim jsonString As String = File.ReadAllText(path)
    Dim mytable As datatablesnet = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of datatablesnet)(jsonString)
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(mytable))
End Sub
```

I get an error and analising the response i see that it was (was added in the end ***{"d":null}***:

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":57,"recordsFiltered":57,"data":[["Airi","Satou","Accountant","Tokyo","28th Nov 08","$162,700"],["Angelica","Ramos","Chief Executive Officer (CEO)","London","9th Oct 09","$1,200,000"],["Ashton","Cox","Junior Technical Author","San Francisco","12th Jan 09","$86,000"],["Bradley","Greer","Software Engineer","London","13th Oct 12","$132,000"],["Brenden","Wagner","Software Engineer","San Francisco","7th Jun 11","$206,850"],["Brielle","Williamson","Integration Specialist","New York","2nd Dec 12","$372,000"],["Bruno","Nash","Software Engineer","London","3rd May 11","$163,500"],["Caesar","Vance","Pre-Sales Support","New York","12th Dec 11","$106,450"],["Cara","Stevens","Sales Assistant","New York","6th Dec 11","$145,600"],["Cedric","Kelly","Senior Javascript Developer","Edinburgh","29th Mar 12","$433,060"]]}{"d":null}
```

**Test3** Load JSON from file to string, convert it to datablesnet object and then serealize it and return it

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json), System.Web.Services.WebMethod(True)>
Public Shared Function getdata5(a As Integer) As String
    Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/teste.json")
    Dim jsonString As String = File.ReadAllText(path)
    Dim mytable As datatablesnet = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of datatablesnet)(jsonString)
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer

    Return serializer.Serialize(mytable)
End Function
```

The result is the same from **Test1**:

```
{d: "{  "draw": 1,  "recordsTotal": 57,  "recordsFilter ... gh",      "29th Mar 12",      "$433,060"    ]  ]}"}
```

I really need to get rid of the **.d** node, receiving the JSON directly from *response* and not from *response.d*. Is there any way I can achieve this from page webmethod ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227427/what-does-d-means-in-asp-net-webservice-response. It's a security hardening mechanism, so you probably don't want to change this.

Comment: You can write a wrapper javascript method to get proper JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I really need to get rid of the `.d` node, receiving the JSON directly
>   from response and not from `response.d`. Is there any way I can achieve
>   this from page `WebMethod`?

Yes, there is. You can write the result directly to response:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod(True)>
Public Shared Sub getdata(a As Integer)
    Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/teste.json")
    Dim jsonString As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(jsonString)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
End Sub
```

In case that you need to do it in multiple classes in your code, you can easily create a shared `Sub WriteJsonToResponse(obj as Object)` and in the body of the method, first serialize the `obj` to json using `JavaScriptSerializer` or `Newtonsoft.JsonConvert`, then write it to the response like above method.

Comment: off-topic, but you also can switch to Web API and host Web API in your site, side by side of Web Forms.

Comment: The answer is tested with the same file which you provided, without any problem. Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mandarory use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
```

That solved my problem.

Comment: Isn't this advice already provided by Reza's answer (which actually attempts to educate researchers instead of simply dumping a snippet)?